# Differences between RC lipo batteries and Li-Polymer batteries in phones/power banks?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

From what I found from WikiPedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery), RC lipo batteries and the Li-Polymer batteries in phones/power banks (like this: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08NPSRS1Y/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08NPSRS1Y)) are the same, they are both Lithium polymer battery (lipo is just a short form).

If so, what are the differences between them?

People are saying RC lipo batteries are dangerous and people buy safety bags for them (like https://www.amazon.com/s?k=lipo+bag). But people don't talk about this for Li-Polymer batteries in cellphones. The RC lipo batteries also have protection, as I found here: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TS2GVS3/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TS2GVS3). Is it not enough?

> 【SAFETY &Quality GUARANTEE】The lipo rc battery Built-in protection mechanism ensures safe charging and use.It comes with a balance lead protector, it can effectively prevent the plug from falling off.

The max output current from the Li-Polymer batteries in phone or power banks are usually limited, but the RC lipo batteries are not.

Comment: people don't normally handle cellphone batteries and connect them to an unspecific charger

Answer (score 0):

There is no much difference in the batteries themselves, but how they are being used and handled.

RC batteries get rough usage mechanically, they can get shocks, dents and puncture damage while operating the device they are in, and careless storing by throwing them around in toolboxes and contacts getting shorted by metal objects rolling around with the batteries, etc.

Same applies to electrical usage. They get charged and discharged at their maximun current, or even beyond them, they get drained to below safe voltage levels, and may be overcharged by manually operating the chargers. The batteries don't handle that without some damage.

Sometimes the batteries or circuits they are in don't contain any battery protection circuitry to prevent improper electrical usage.

Now, normally batteries in powerbanks and phones don't get such use mechanically and electrically. The circuits often contain battery protection to prevent overcurrents and over/undervoltages.

Comment: The RC battery I linked (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TS2GVS3) also has protection. Is it enough?

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: Not sure what protection it says from the description: "The lipo rc battery Built-in protection mechanism ensures safe charging and use.It comes with a balance lead protector, it can effectively prevent the plug from falling off."

Comment: I guess there is no over-discharge and short circuit protection that power bank/phone usually has. Isn't it?

Comment: Worth mentioning as well - RC batteries tend to be much larger and have much more capacity than cell phone batteries.

Comment: The Amazon No-Name-Brand RC battery with a protection circuit is spec'd with a C of 5.2Ah and max current of 50C= 250A! That would produce a spectacular explosion and fire. My RC batteries are Name-Brand and never exploded or caught on fire. My Name-Brand 16Ah power bank has two 1A and one 2A outputs.